# How to model ternary relationships

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, entity-framework-5

What's the best way to map entities to a ternary relationship with EF5?

For example, three entities:

```
Bike
Crash
Person
```

Then there would be a ternary relationship to know:

1. The bike of which person was in the crash X
2. The persons involved in the crash X between bikes X and Y
3. In what crashes were involved person A on bike B

etc.

How should I create my entities?
Is the only possibility to create a new entity for the ternary relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Suppose that there are `Person-Bike` combinations that can exists without `Crash`es (thank god). So you can create a binary relationship (junction table) `PersonBike` having FK's to person and bike, assuming that bikes are not owned by specific persons. EF can handle this a a many-to-many relationship without an association class in the model.

Then, too bad, Person-Bike combinations can get involved in crashes. Maybe more than two combinations in one crash. Basically you could have a collection `PersonBikes` in `Crash`. In that case there would be no association class in the model at all. But if you want to know more about the association between `Crash` and `PersonBike`, e.g. who is guilty of the crash, you need a junction table between both: `CrashPersonBike` with FK's to `Crash` and `PersonBike` and one or more fields describing the association (like guilty yes/no). This would require an association class in the EF model.

**Option 2**

Bikes have specific owners (persons): let `Person` have a `Bikes` collection (the table Bike has an FK to Person). Now it suffices to describe a crash only by the bikes that are involved, because the bikes determine the person. So `Crash` can have a `Bikes` collection (again: no association classes in the model) or an association class `CrashBike` that contains more details as described above.

**Option 3**

A "true" ternary relationship that requires an association class (`CrashPersonBike`) in the model, with or without extra details.

In all cases you need business logic to prevent the same persons (or bikes in option 1 and 3) from getting involved in one crash. Option 1 and 2 have an additional benefit in that the model can describe person-bike combinations apart from crashes. Whether it should be 1 or 2 depends on bike-person ownership.

Comment: Gert, thank you very much for your detailed answer!. Now it will be a matter of thinking which one fits better in my application.

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to understand how you can manage option 1 (having a collection of `PersonBike`s in `Crash`) with "no association class in the model". If I give `PersonBike` an FK to `Crash`,  `PersonBike` becomes an entity and I lose the direct many-to-many relationship between `Person` and `Bike`. Is there a way to avoid that? I'm using EF4, by the way.